# Should I change SSD?

Tags: linux, storage, ssd

Demsg shows this

```
EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_ext_get_blocks: inode #7743113: (comm
flush-8:0) bad extent address iblock: 3503, depth: 1 pblock 0
EXT4-fs (sda1): delayed block allocation failed for inode 7743113 at logical
offset 3503 with max blocks 1 with error -5

This should not happen!!  Data will be lost
EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_ext_get_blocks: inode #7743113: (comm
flush-8:0) bad extent address iblock: 3509, depth: 1 pblock 0
EXT4-fs (sda1): delayed block allocation failed for inode 7743113 at logical
offset 3509 with max blocks 2 with error -5

This should not happen!!  Data will be lost
EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_ext_get_blocks: inode #7743113: (comm
flush-8:0) bad extent address iblock: 3513, depth: 1 pblock 0
EXT4-fs (sda1): delayed block allocation failed for inode 7743113 at logical
offset 3513 with max blocks 1 with error -5

This should not happen!!  Data will be lost
EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_ext_get_blocks: inode #7743113: (comm
flush-8:0) bad extent address iblock: 3519, depth: 1 pblock 0
EXT4-fs (sda1): delayed block allocation failed for inode 7743113 at logical
offset 3519 with max blocks 1 with error -5

This should not happen!!  Data will be lost
EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_ext_get_blocks: inode #7743113: (comm
flush-8:0) bad extent address iblock: 3525, depth: 1 pblock 0
EXT4-fs (sda1): delayed block allocation failed for inode 7743113 at logical
offset 3525 with max blocks 1 with error -5

This should not happen!!  Data will be lost
EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_ext_get_blocks: inode #7743113: (comm
flush-8:0) bad extent address iblock: 3528, depth: 1 pblock 0
EXT4-fs (sda1): delayed block allocation failed for inode 7743113 at logical
offset 3528 with max blocks 1 with error -5

This should not happen!!  Data will be lost
possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.
EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_ext_get_blocks: inode #7743113: (comm
flush-8:0) bad extent address iblock: 3529, depth: 1 pblock 0
EXT4-fs (sda1): delayed block allocation failed for inode 7743113 at logical
offset 3529 with max blocks 3 with error -5

This should not happen!!  Data will be lost
```

Also I can't do a lot with the disk. Simple commands like

fails

```
root@host [/home1]# rm -rf cprestore
rm: cannot remove
`cprestore/home4/site/public_html/hello/cache/site.com/http%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Fh%2F20019%2Fszh%2F%25E6%25B1%2589%25E5%258F%25A3%25E4%25B8%25AD%25E5%258D%258E%25E5%2585%25A8%25E5%259B%25BD%25E6%2580%25BB%25E5%25B7%25A5%25E4%25BC%259A%25E6%2597%25A7%25E5%259D%2580':
Input/output error
rm: cannot remove
`cprestore/home4/site/public_html/hello/cache/site.com/http%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Ft%2Ffoo%2Fszh%2F%25D7%25A7%25D7%2598%25D7%2592%25D7%2595%25D7%25A8%25D7%2599%25D7%2594%3A%25D7%2590%25D7%2595%25D7%25A0%25D7%2599%25D7%2595%25D7%25AA_%25D7%259E%25D7%25A2%25D7%25A4%25D7%2599%25D7%259C%25D7%2599%25D':
Input/output error
rm: cannot remove
`cprestore/home4/site/public_html/hello/cache/site.com/http%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Fp%2F%25E9%259F%25A9%25E6%2588%2590%25E7%258F%25A0%25E4%25B8%258D%25E9%259B%2585%25E8%25A7%2586%25E9%25A2%2591%25E5%25AE%258C%25E6%2595%25B4%25E7%2589%2588%2Fszh%2F1':
Input/output error
```

My fstab is like this:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Wed Nov  1 00:29:46 2000
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=9fac7ae7-9948-4612-88dc-e652fc4ceb73 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=1daa52c7-a5da-464d-a4c7-2ee19ef017af /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
UUID=12649fb1-fd53-4558-8a2a-79692ada8b19 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/usr/tmpDSK             /tmp                    ext3    defaults,noauto        0 0
/dev/sda1               /home1                  auto    auto,noatime,defaults        0 2
/dev/sdb1               /home2                  auto    auto,noatime,defaults        0 2
/dev/sdc1               /home3                  auto    auto,noatime,defaults        0 2
```

As you see I check every reboot

My provider said he did some fchk and now it's running again. However, it's been happening several time. Each time it happens it costs me a lot. I wonder if this is hardware or sotware?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `smartctl` which gives you access [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) on the drive. It has numerous options and some special for SSDs, so read its man page. Generally, if your drive will report a hardware error, it's time to backup (if you haven't done that already) and replace it - today's hard drives have a reasonable spare space for bad block reallocations, so if it reports problems, chances are that this buffer has already been used (or something else is wrong with the drive). Yet that doesn't necessarily mean there would be no other uses for the drive (other than an underlay for a table).

Answer (score 0):

From the command line you can use fsck to do an immediate disk check /sbin/fsck on most distros. For example:

```
% sudo /sbin/fsck -t ext4 /dev/sda1
```

As a word of caution: unmount the file system first! 
Type `man fsck` and read about it for more information.

Sometimes this check can seemingly perform miracles with a drive but don't hold your breath. This appears to be a bad drive. SSD are NOT very reliable in my experience.